# How to check the number (counting) of elements by class from a batchdataset from keras?

Tags: python, data-science, tf.keras

My main objective is to use a CNN later on. And I found a way to divide it into 3 parts: train, validation, and test datasets respectively. However, I don't know if they are balanced. So, I need to count the elements for each class in a specific dataset.

```
dataset = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  DATASET_DIRECTION,
  seed = 37,
  image_size = (128, 128),
  batch_size = 25, 
  labels = 'inferred'
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might not be the best way but I managed to get this...

```
dataset_unbatched = tuple(dataset.unbatch())
labels = []
for (image,label) in dataset_unbatched:
    labels.append(label.numpy())
labels = pd.Series(labels)
count = labels.value_counts()
print(counts)
```

This should give the number of images you had in each class displayed as a pandas Dataframe.